Caffeinate doesn't work on Macbook Pro with lid closed?
I have an old Macbook Pro with Big Sur (11.7.10) that I use to execute an Applescript that typically runs for 1-2 hours. The first thing I do in this script is
set caffeinatePid to do shell script "caffeinate -d > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"

to prevent the computer from going to sleep (and to be able to kill the caffeinate process at the end of the script) but it doesn't work. The screen sleeps after the set time (3 minutes) and this pauses the execution of the script. The only workaround I have found so far is to connect to the machine using Screen Sharing.
Why does caffeinate not work? How should I use it in this situation?

Sounds like the remote display is triggering what used to be called closed clamshell mode. Can we assume you connected power, keyboard and display to the Mac while the lid is closed? Have you told the Mac not to sleep when the display is off? https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-sleep-and-wake-settings-mchle41a6ccd/mac toggle top for Big Sur, see Keep your Mac from going to sleep automatically: Click Power Adapter, then select “Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off.”

It is a Macbook Pro so it has everything connected. I want it to sleep 99 % of the time, it is just when I run this script I want it stay awake - hence my use of caffeinate.

Have you looked at the Options in man caffeinate? It seems to me that Apple has not maintained caffeinate very well (on Ventura my caffeinate man page is dated 2012!). I've had more luck with the -s option - but you have to keep your Mac plugged into a charger/power source.

Makes very good sense DB. Had to rule out a quick fix. My hunch is caffeinate calls an older assertion and you’ll need this one “If you prefer to hold the display awake for a longer period and you know how long you'd like to hold it, consider taking assertion kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleDisplaySleep using IOPMAssertionCreateWithDescription API instead.” But the developer site is pretty opaque for scripting this…

Theoretically, swift can run as a script - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26688103/475228

The '-d' option is just to keep the display alive. What happens when you use '-i'?

@Mockman No (noticable) change with ´-i´ or ´-u´

@Seamus No (noticable) change with  ´-s´.

@bmike After doing more research the problem might be another one than what I initially thought. This script runs Safari and when you use Safari "manually", if you send a tab to the background, its processing grinds to a halt (I assume this is for energy saving reasons). I think I have the same issue here, despite the tab being in the front. It seems Safari slows down the processing of web pages when the lid is closed. It works as expected if I connect with Screen Sharing but when I disconnect that it slows down to almost stop.

Interesting find on another thing to consider with Apple's energy savings changes to the OS d-b

@d-b: Note that before the -s option can become effective, it also requires the charger to be plugged in. (just checking).

@Seamus It is plugged in. I don't, any longer, think the issue is caffeinate/sleep but something with Safari. Any ideas how I can check if the machine is sleeping or not, without the checking waking it up? Even if it is sleeping it responds to ping, ssh etc.
